# PHP/MySQL Loop Help

Tags: php, mysql

I need to insert a 6 digit key into my database. I can't figure out how to do the loop part. If the key is in use I need to keep generating a new key and checking it to make sure its not in use.

```
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as numrecords FROM id WHERE id='".$generated_id."'"); 
if ($row['numrecords'] >= 1)
{ 
//key is in use generate new key and loop to make sure its not in use
} 
else 
{ 
//insert key
}
mysql_close();
```

Thanks

Comment: @R3dBu77: Any reason why you can't make that database field a unique index?

Comment: Are you trying to replace an auto-increment ID?

Comment: Why aren't you using an AUTO_INCREMENT column so there's no searching? (Assuming that's what you're after, a unique primary key)

Comment: elusive yes. i cant use auto-icrement because i cant have the numbers in order. 1,2,3,4,5 etc.

Comment: @R3dBu77: Why not? SQL-queries in loops is not what you want. Trust me. Depending on how you're generating that ID (i guess that it is based on some kind of randomness), this could run forever (theoretically). You'd be better of using some kind of hash that identifies your content (whatever content that is).

Comment: Its for a video site. Video.php?id=. The uploader has the option to pick unlisted. If the pick unlisted the video will not be posted on the site but anyone with the id can view it. If I use auto-increment the id's would be sequential. A person could just keep adding 1 to the id and view every video.

Comment: @R3dBu77: Then use a hash. Use an auto-increment ID and add a salt. Hash the result and use it as unique key.

Comment: Thank you elusive thats a great idea! I will hash them with crc32 or crc32b to keep the id nice and small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add a UNIQUE key constraint on the column:

```
ALTER TABLE id ADD UNIQUE id;
```

Then you can use this PHP code:

```
while (1) {
  // generate ID
  $sql = "INSERT....";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  if ($result !== false) { break; }
}
```

Comment: Very sensible, I would suggest an edit to make clear that the SQL in the loop is an `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
do {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as numrecords FROM id WHERE id='".$generated_id."'");
    if ($row['numrecords'] >= 1)
    { 
        //key is in use generate new key and loop to make sure its not in use
        // regenerate $generated_id
    }
} while ($row['numrecords'] >= 1);

//insert key

mysql_close();
```

Or to clean things up a bit:

```
while (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM id WHERE id='".$generated_id."'"))) {
   $generated_id = generateKey();
}

// insert key

mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using such code to generate loop, simply put a test at the beginning:

```
while(true)
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("query goes here"));
if($row) { continue; }
// rest of code
```

Don't forget to add some break; when code reach too many iterations or you found non-existent sequence.